# Pass the function to the dialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin

someone know a different approach to pass the function to the DialogFragment than using callback ?   This approach need to respect Android OS (killing components by system).

Comment: You'll need to provide more info on what you have so far, what exactly you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried. `onAttach` could be a solution, depending on your specific scenario.

Comment: onAttach u mean callback (autogenerated by android studio when u create a fragment), I want something new :)

Comment: Use a shared `ViewModel`. Have the `DialogFragment` update that `ViewModel`. That `ViewModel` can then inform the activity or other fragments about those changes via `LiveData`.

Answer (score 2):

not sure what you want but you can create a function as public var in your fragment like this:

```
    class MyFragment : Fragment(){
    ...

    var myFunction: (() -> Unit)? = null
    ...
    }
```

if you want to pass variables or return something change your function to:

```
    var myFunction: ((text: String, b: Boolean) -> String)? = null
```

you can call this function by calling: 
`myFunction.invoke()` 

and pass parameters like:
 `myFunction.invoke("title", true)`

implement `myFunction` when creating the fragment instance:

```
    val fragment = MyFragment .newInstance().apply {
        myFunction = {
             //do something
        }

        //with parametrs
        myFunction = { s: String, b: Boolean
             //do something
             return "text"
        }
    }
```